# How to monitor progress for LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE for mysql import?

Tags: mysql, progress-bar

I import a bunch of tables using the LOAD INFILE feature of mysql.

```
mysql >  LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'database-dump-of-table.xml' INTO TABLE mytable ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<row>';
```

This process might take some time depending on the size of the dump. Is there a way of showing a progress information?

Comment: BTW: If converted to CSV the import is sped up DRASTICALLY and the progress information might be superfluous then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843258/how-to-improve-performance-of-a-mysql-load-xml-local-infile-table-import